# How to Check if a Property used in an Expression

Tags: c#

I want to check a given `Expression<Func<TSource,bool>>` uses a given Property of `TSource` or not, for example i have Type `Customer`:

```
public class Customer 
{
    public bool Active{get;set;}
    // ...
}
```

And i have the flowing Expressions:

```
var exp1 = q => q.Name.Contains("a") && q.Addresses.Any(x=>x.City.Contains("b")) && q.Active;
var exp2 = q => q.Name.Contains("a") && q.Addresses.Any(x=>x.City.Contains("b"));
var exp3 = q => q.Name.Contains("a") && q.Addresses.Any(x=>x.City.Contains("b")) && q.Active || !q.Active;
var exp4 = q => q.Name.Contains("a") && q.Addresses.Any(x=>x.City.Contains("b")) && q.Active == isActive; // isActive is a variable.
```

Or any Expression like so, how can i check if that expression used the Property Active or no (if that possible). thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I guess a dirty way would be to just do this:

```
bool containsActive = exp1.ToString().Contains(".Active");
```

However, please keep in mind if you have an expression like this:

```
var exp2 = q => q.Name.Contains("a") && 
    q.Addresses.Any(x=>x.City.Contains(".Active"));
```

That will also return `true` because the whole expression treated like a string has `.Active`.

Comment: I guessed in this way, but am looking for better way thank you i will use it if no other solutions and i will add the parameter name before '.Active' to avoid the second expression cases.